# How to delete a line in ubuntu using sed with linenumber stored in a variable?

Tags: ubuntu, sed, line-numbers

I am writing a script to delete a line of text file in ubuntu, my script asks the user which line they want to delete and store the line number to a variable. However, I don't know how to use sed with variable, I have searched many topic about sed. Unluckily, there are only thing like this:

```
sed '2d' file1 > file2
```

Which I want is

```
read index
# I have tried:
sed ($index)d file1 > file2 # didn't work
sed $(index)d file1 > file2 # didn't work
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a user-defined variable in sed code is asking for trouble -- sed cannot tell that you meant to put a number there if the user enters `s/^/rm -rf \//e;`. Instead use awk:

```
awk -v line="$index" 'NR != line' filename
```

If you really want to do it with sed,

```
sed "${index}d" filename
```

will work **as long as the user doesn't try to mess with you**. If the user messes with you, it will explode in horrible ways.

Comment: ex of security `if [ $( echo "${index}" | grep -E -c '^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+[[:space:]]*$' ) -gt 0 ];then sed "${index}d" filename;fi`

Comment: Thank you, it work! I only want to find out a method to do this (however, I'm new to ubunu, so I only know sed). So,  I think I will use awk for this.